# GDX NullPointerException Enemy Updating

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, libgdx

```
for (int i = enemigos.size-1; i >= 0; i--){
        enemigos.get(i).posicion.x += enemigos.get(i).speed * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();      <== HERE NULL POINTER
        enemigos.get(i).update(dt);

        if(enemigos.get(i).posicion.x < 0 - enemigos.get(i).currentFrame.getRegionWidth() || enemigos.get(i).posicion.x > 600){
            enemigos.removeIndex(i);
        }
    }
```

This code is inside the `update(float dt)` in the SpriteManager of my project where I update all objects in the game.

This one reads the enemy list and update the position every time ...

But when I begin the game, it stays 0-20 seconds until sometimes catchs the null pointer in the position.x update of the enemy.

Why?

ERROR :

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at juannmcc.manager.pescador.SpriteManager.update(SpriteManager.java:131)
    at juannmcc.pantallas.pescador.PantallaJuego.render(PantallaJuego.java:39)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
    at juannmcc.game.pescador.Juego.render(Juego.java:48)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:207)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
```

Comment: You could start by checking exactly what becomes null. To find out why you might want to investigate further.

Comment: Take a look at line `Juego.java:48`

Comment: In render only are super(); and in PantallaJuego : render is good.

Comment: You need to set a breakpoint and determine which variable exactly is `null`. Are you using an IDE where you can do so, and inspect variables?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
enemigos.removeIndex(i++);
```

After you remove one enemy, you need to go back one index.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But now it gives me the same error and this one sometimes : 

    Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
 at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array.get(Array.java:127)
 at juannmcc.manager.pescador.SpriteManager.update(SpriteManager.java:145)


The number 7 of IndexOutOfBoundsException sometimes is 3 , or 5 or similar too. :s

Comment: If you put a break after you remove will you still get the error? Also, at which line you get the error ?